# unpack(self.fillColor) coming back as "nil" no matter what I try?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

First post here, but longtime user of others' solutions. I've enrolled in a Lua programming course this semester and we are on our very first assignment. My question may be very easy to answer but for someone who has never worked in a language like Lua, it is driving me up the wall!

The basis of the game is to create a board of colored squares and let the user touch them to select them. On touch, the square gets bigger and stays bigger. Then, if the next one touched matches the first one in color, they are to disappear/delete themselves and then once all the squares are gone, the game restarts. Here's the code, with irrelevant bits removed.

```
-- Get screen dimensions in easier to reference variables
maxXValue = display.contentWidth;
maxYValue = display.contentHeight;

-- Set up table of boxes to play game with
-- May have a better way to do this...
gameBoard = {}
for i = 1, 16 do
   if i == 1 then boxNum = display.newRect(0, 0, (0.25*maxXValue-5), 
    (0.25*maxYValue-5));
    table.insert(gameBoard, boxNum);
   elseif i == 2 then boxNum = display.newRect((0.25*maxXValue), 0, 
    (0.25*maxXValue-5), (0.25*maxYValue-5));
    table.insert(gameBoard, boxNum);
   elseif i == 3 then boxNum = display.newRect((0.5*maxXValue), 0, 
    (0.25*maxXValue-5), (0.25*maxYValue-5));
    table.insert(gameBoard, boxNum);
   elseif i == 4 then boxNum = display.newRect((0.75*maxXValue), 0, 
    (0.25*maxXValue-5), (0.25*maxYValue-5));
    table.insert(gameBoard, boxNum);
   elseif i == 5 then boxNum = display.newRect(0, (0.25*maxYValue), 
    (0.25*maxXValue-5), (0.25*maxYValue-5));
    table.insert(gameBoard, boxNum);
   elseif i == 6 then boxNum = display.newRect((0.25*maxXValue), (0.25*maxYValue), 
    (0.25*maxXValue-5), (0.25*maxYValue-5));
    table.insert(gameBoard, boxNum);
   elseif i == 7 then boxNum = display.newRect((0.5*maxXValue), (0.25*maxYValue), 
    (0.25*maxXValue-5), (0.25*maxYValue-5));
    table.insert(gameBoard, boxNum);
   elseif i == 8 then boxNum = display.newRect((0.75*maxXValue), ((0.25*maxYValue)), 
    (0.25*maxXValue-5), (0.25*maxYValue-5));
    table.insert(gameBoard, boxNum);
   elseif i == 9 then boxNum = display.newRect(0, (0.5*maxYValue), 
    (0.25*maxXValue-5), (0.25*maxYValue-5));
    table.insert(gameBoard, boxNum);
   elseif i == 10 then boxNum = display.newRect((0.25*maxXValue), (0.5*maxYValue), 
    (0.25*maxXValue-5), (0.25*maxYValue-5));
    table.insert(gameBoard, boxNum);
   elseif i == 11 then boxNum = display.newRect((0.5*maxXValue), (0.5*maxYValue), 
    (0.25*maxXValue-5), (0.25*maxYValue-5));
    table.insert(gameBoard, boxNum);
   elseif i == 12 then boxNum = display.newRect((0.75*maxXValue), (0.5*maxYValue), 
    (0.25*maxXValue-5), (0.25*maxYValue-5));
    table.insert(gameBoard, boxNum);
   elseif i == 13 then boxNum = display.newRect(0, (0.75*maxYValue), 
    (0.25*maxXValue-5), (0.25*maxYValue-5));
    table.insert(gameBoard, boxNum);
   elseif i == 14 then boxNum = display.newRect((0.25*maxXValue), (0.75*maxYValue), 
    (0.25*maxXValue-5), (0.25*maxYValue-5));
    table.insert(gameBoard, boxNum);
   elseif i == 15 then boxNum = display.newRect((0.5*maxXValue), (0.75*maxYValue), 
    (0.25*maxXValue-5), (0.25*maxYValue-5));
    table.insert(gameBoard, boxNum);
   elseif i == 16 then boxNum = display.newRect((0.75*maxXValue), (0.75*maxYValue), 
    (0.25*maxXValue-5), (0.25*maxYValue-5));
    table.insert(gameBoard, boxNum);
    end
end

--Irrelevant code here

local selected = {};

local function toucher (event)
   local red, green, blue = unpack(self.fillColor); -- ERROR APPEARS HERE
   table.insert(selected, self, red, green, blue)
   event.target:scale(1.1, 1.1)
   event.target:toFront();
   if selected[2] == event.target then
    if (selected[1].red == selected[2].red and selected[1].green == selected[2].green 
        and selected[1].blue == selected[2].blue) then
        selected[1]:removeSelf();
        selected[2]:removeSelf();
    end
    selected[1] = selected[2];
    selected[2] = nil;
   end
--[[Code to go here will tell the program to restart. Want to get a single iteration before
moving to this.]]
end
for i = 1, 16 do gameBoard[i]:addEventListener("touch", toucher);
end
```

In the "toucher" function, I am trying to use the unpack(self.fillColor) function to get the colors of the square that was selected to save for comparison later. From my research, this is one of the easier ways to read the colors back out of an object. When the user touches the square, however, I get the following error:

main.lua:121:attempt to index global 'self' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
 main.lua:121:in function < main.lua:120 >
 ?:in function < ?:169 >

I've read up on how the self and the event.target objects work but both give the same error when I attempt to dereference them for anything but their name (which prints "nil"). I feel like I am probably understanding a very simple scoping concept incorrectly. Other operations using event.target and self, like the resize and toFront() operations, are working perfectly so I don't quite understand why getting properties of the object doesn't work.

I know my code isn't pretty or super efficient but I'm really only worried about getting it to work. The assignment is due this week and I've been trying to figure out the issue on my own for several days now. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no object `self` in that function. All event listeners have an event parameter, that has a `target` property, which refers to the object that dispatched the event. [More info here](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/events/touchMultitouch/index.html).

In your case, you are missing a line to specify `self`, like:

```
local function toucher (event)
    local self = event.target -- This line is missing.
    local red, green, blue = unpack(self.fillColor)
```

Never heard of the `.fillColor` property, though, So i am guessing you are specifying it yourself, if not, wrap the function `setFillColor` to save the colors, like so:

```
function gameBoard[1]:saveFillColor(r, g, b, a) -- New function that saves the color and sets it.
    self.fillColor = {r, g, b, a}
    self:setFillColor(r, g, b, a)
end
```

`self` is only available when a function gets called as part of an object, like `gameBoard[1]:toucher()` with the `:` You can read more info about this [here](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.html).

Comment: Don't forget your `local` keyword.

Comment: Hmm, shows how new I am to the language. I was under the impression from my research that `self` and `event.target` are about the same thing. `event.target` does gives the same error though, when used in that spot. Is there a decent way to get the color of the object that you are aware of? I actually found `.fillColor` on another stackoverflow link, but I can't seem to dig it back up now.

Comment: You should set `.fillColor` yourself, after calling `:setFillColor()`. There is also a `.fill` property, but that is userdata and cannot be unpacked.

Comment: I've added a wrapper function that will allow you to save the applied color to the `.fillColor` property. Be careful though, because `:setFillColor` accepts 1, 2, 3, or 4 parameters, and each can do different things: https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/ShapeObject/setFillColor.html And this should be the link you were talking about, as you can see, you need to specify it yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239054/how-to-get-colour-of-rect-on-touch-in-corona-sdk